# Data-Model with 3 tier document hierarchy in mongodb

Tags: performance, mongodb, data-modeling

In my project, we are having a typical customer subscription scenario where in we have to store the details in mongo. We have finalized the following data model for this scenario:

i.e. a customer can have multiple subscriptions and each subscription can have multiple activation codes.

```
{
  "CustomerCompany" : "abc",
  "CustomerEmail" : "abc@abc.com",
  "CustomerID" : "124598",
  "CustomerName" : "abc xyz",
  "CustomerType" : "Indivisual",
  "IsOurCustomer" : true,
  "Subscriptions" : [{
      "ContentDeliveryFormat" : "XML",
      "ContentDeliverySchedule" : "Daily",
      "ContentProviderName" : "asdf",
      "ContentType" : "CFR",
      "ContentCategory" : "CFR",
      "SubscriptionExpiryDate" : "11/19/2014 15:22:39:800 IST",
      "SubscriptionID" : "111",
      "ActivationCount" : 1,
      "Activations" : [{
          "ActivationCode" : "35f110b8-1b59-44c5-9874-adcc9d008898",
          "ActivationCodeGenDate" : "05/23/2014 15:22:59:997 IST",
          "ActivationExpiryDate" : "05/28/2014 15:22:59:997 IST",
          "ActivationDate" : null,
          "ActivationStatus" : "Unused"
        }],
      "SubscriptionStatus" : "Subscribed"
    }],
  "_id" : ObjectId("537f1a7ce96e0b34e98b8de7")
}
```

As i am new to mongodb and a detailed search on this could'nt convince me i am posting my query here.

I have the following two questions:

- Is the modeling correct wrt the best practices to be followed in mongodb?
- If i follow this approach, then with current data model a simple
  search of document with input as activation-code with result in worst
  case efficiency of O(n3). And i think if the system scales up, this
  approach will be a big NO-NO.

Can experts plz comment on this scenario?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the following.  Documents are written to disk one after another.  When you add more stuff into arrays at a later time, the document grows -- and might need to be moved to accommodate the data addition.  Also, most likely you array values will be indexed -- which means all those indexes will need to be updated as the document is moved.  Finally, for your app, when you load customer data, do you really need to load ALL the subscriptions and activation keys as well?  If the answer is NO, then you should consider the overall picture I am describing and possibly keep it in separate collections.   The bigger the document, the fewer of them fit into RAM.   Bottom line is, how much dynamic growth do you expect within the document once it is created  initially?